# epoch, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, verbose

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data

I have 1260 training data, 161 validation data, and 72 testing data.

The train_batch size 21, valid's : 7, train's : 12

Then how to set it into epoch, batch size, verbose and steps per epoch?

I define the generator like this:

```
model.fit_generator(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=20, validation_data=valid batches, validation-steps=10, epochs=5, verbose=2)
```

Comment: perhaps you wanna add some more info, like how your generator is yielding your data into your `fit_generator`. Keep in mind that what you've written is **NOT** a generator, but a `fit_generator` which enables a model to train on continuously in-flowing data

Comment: i use imagedatagenerator